# How to get MR stats in gitlab using git cli?

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How to fetch final MR lines inserted deleted and changed files after multiple commits are done under one MR? I need to do it using git cli.

Answer (score 0):

MRs are available as refs on the remote repository. You can checkout MRs, run `git diff`, or any other usual git operation on MRs.

One way: [checkout the MR locally](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#checkout-merge-requests-locally-through-the-head-ref) then use `git diff`.

```sh
git fetch origin merge-requests/123/head:mr-origin-123 && git checkout mr-origin-123
git diff --stat HEAD..target-branch
```

Comment: I am trying this way -`git ls-remote origin 'refs/merge-requests/*/head'`. Using above way, How to get the first line commit Id and do checkout in generic manner and diff stat each for each MR.